# Passing page variable to function in PHP

Tags: php

How do I pass variable itself to the function ? here's snippet

```
$user_name;
$user_id;

function set($variable,$value)
{
   $variable = $value ;
}
```

to call set($user_name,'abc');set($user_id,'abc123')

i want to set the value of $user_name,$user_id.

thanks

Comment: Can you please restructure your question, I can't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why would you want to do that, but you can use the `&` operator. This will make your variable [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead of value.

```
function set(&$variable,$value) {
   $variable = $value ;
}
```

In this case, the below code will print `10`:

```
$user_name = 5;

function set(&$variable,$value) {
   $variable = $value ;
}

set($user_name, 10);
echo $user_name;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tW8sWB)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefix the variable with a `&` in the function header, you give the function a reference to the original variable, so it will alter the variable in its original context.

```
function set(&$variable,$value)
{
  $variable = $value ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the $user_name variable in the function use global $user_name; 
If you want to return a variable to the script outside the function scope use return $variable; in the function.